# getting imageWithContensOfFile to pick the proper graphic

Tags: ios, ios5, retina-display

Im switchting to imageWithContentsOfFile insteaf of imageNamed to avoid memory leaks, and the only way ive found to load an image is by the absolute path to the file i want:

```
UIImage *rightCap = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rightcap@2x" ofType:@"png"]];
```

my problem is it will no longer automatically load the correct graphic for retina/nonretina displays, is there a modification to this that allows that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the explicit identification of the @2x from your filename. Your code should be:

```
UIImage *rightCap = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rightcap" ofType:@"png"]];
```

The iOS will do the right thing depending on the platform. That is, this works for retina and iPad variations to your files.